# Dealing with empty data frames (<0 rows>) when using pipes in dplyr

Tags: r, if-statement, exception, dataframe, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr` to filter a data frame

```
DF <- structure(list(Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), Balance = c(1000L, 3000L, 2500L)), .Names = c("Category", 
"Balance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

in the following way:

```
DF %>%
filter(Category == 'A') %>%
select(Balance) %>%
sum(., na.rm=T)
```

It all works fine until the filter that I use returns an empty data frame, e.g. using `filter(Category == 'B')` returns

`<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

When this happens I want to return 0, but my pipe breaks. I tried using `ifelse` but my syntax was incorrect:

```
DF %>%
filter(Category == 'B') %>%
select(Balance) %>% ifelse(nrow(.)==0, 0, sum(., na.rm=T))
```

Another possibility would be to use `tryCatch` but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into the pipe.

To sum up, I want to return 0 when the data frame is empty and the sum when it has other values.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF %>%
  filter(Category == 'B') %>%
  .$Balance %>%
  sum(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: That was easier than I expected, thanks. Can you explain what this extra lines does?

Comment: `.` is your data that is passed on from previous pipe, `$Balance` select the column as vector. Try: `DF$Balance` it gives a numeric vector.

Answer (score 1):

I have one alternative answer, which is more on the line of your question.

```
DF %>%
  filter(Category == 'B') %>%
  select(Balance) %>%
  unlist %>% # unlist so as to make vector
  sum(na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only dplyr functions in the first part of the chain you can do:

```
tempDF = DF %>% 
  filter(Category == "B") %>% 
  select(matches("Balance")) %>% 
  summarize(s = sum(Balance)) 
tempDF = tempDF %>% as.numeric
```

I found this useful because its only at the last step you convert your empty data frame to a vector. This gives me a chance to treat tempDF as a data frame before converting to a 0.